# How to create repeating tasks with Google Tasks API?

Tags: google-api, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

Can't create repeating tasks with Google Tasks API

Google Calendar API `https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource` has `recurrence` key.

```
  "recurrence": [
    string
  ],
```

But I can't find `recurrence` in Google Tasks API.

How I can create repeating tasks with Google Tasks API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Google Tasks API does not support creating repeating tasks.